# Linq query error on mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DesignationID { get; set; }

    public virtual Designation Designation { get; set; }
}


(from emp in dc.Employee 
    select new Employee { Employee = emp , Designation = emp.Designation }).Single();
```

Its giving me error `"Models.Employee does not contain a definition for Employee"` on the line `Employee = emp`

Comment: Can you show your view model (Employee)?

Comment: It is correct, your class named `Employee` does not have a property named `Employee`. According to your `select` clause you're trying to insert an instance of `Employee` into itself.

Comment: you must say that Name = em.Name

Comment: Craig W. , so how should I solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it's simple as error says, your model doesn't contain a definition for `Employee`, So you should write something like this:

```
(from emp in dc.Employee 
    select new Employee { Name = emp.Name ,...
```

If you want a the employee object you can create a view model like this:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public Employee Employee {get; set;}
    public Designation Designation {get; set;}
}
```

Then write your query this way:

```
select new EmployeeViewModel { Employee = emp , Designation = emp.Designation }).Single();
```

Comment: Name = emp.Name will select the whole object of Employee ?

Comment: great I got it , Thanks